# C# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Error being thrown when the `dateString` is the following but worked earlier for a different time, not sure why it isn't working now.

```
 string dateString = "Jul 24, 2015 4:03:51 PM PDT";
            string format = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt PDT";
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
            Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Edited Code:  The error is thrown either of the last two lines, sometimes the first DateTime will execute but not the second.  The prompt window just asks for, first, the earliest date and time which is: Jul 24, 2015 6:26:15 AM PDT.  And then another prompt for the latest DateTime which is:  Jul 24, 2015 4:03:51 PM PDT

```
string afterpromptvalue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter earliest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");
            string beforepromptvalue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter latest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");

            string format = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt PDT";
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            DateTime createdAfter = DateTime.ParseExact(afterpromptvalue, format, provider);
            DateTime createdBefore = DateTime.ParseExact(beforepromptvalue, format, provider);
```

Edited again:  I wanted to put the prompt dialog box code, because this may be the issue.

```
public static class Prompt
{
    public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form();
        prompt.Width = 500;
        prompt.Height = 150;
        prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        prompt.Text = caption;
        prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top=20, Text=text };
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top=50, Width=400 };
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left=350, Width=100, Top=70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just **Convert.ToDateTime(datestring)**

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: What is the error? Have you added 'using System.Globalization'

Comment: Yeah you're right it does run fine.  I think maybe I put an extra space at the end.  However, I'm getting an error when I incorporate the same concept in my code, so at least I know this error not from an invalid format, because it is printing to console correctly.  I'll need to look deeper and maybe create a new question, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure Prompt.ShowDialog returns string which is required?
Or you need to browse some property returned by Prompt.ShowDialog.
Something like -

var instance = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter earliest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");

string afterpromptvalue  = instance.Text;

Comment: @Aamol Yeah, don't know why I wasn't thinking that the prompt dialog box might be the issue.  Thanks I'll try and look into when I have more free time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked at my machine without any error. Try executing it on some other machine or in different solution. If it works means your solution need to be clean and build. If do not work means you you probably missing required references -

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: Got these!  I'll edit my question to post the code that isn't working that I tried to recreate with more simple code.

Answer (score 0):

A common error with date parsing is using `dd` instead of `d`.  With `dd`, a value of `24` will pass, but `9` will not; the latter would have to be `09` instead.  If you use a single `d`, however, then `9`, `09`, and `24` would all be allowed.